# Site Map Generation Symfony2 Bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, sitemap

Does anybody knows a good vendor bundle for symfony2 for Sitemap generation with minimal modifications.

Comment: http://knpbundles.com/search?q=sitemap

Comment: Well thanks, I tried all of them. The problem is some of them are using doctrine and mongodb bundles. And I want a bundle that is neutral (non dependent on any other bundle). And easy to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [this article](http://enarion.net/programming/php/symfony2/xml-sitemaps/) is a good primer for creating a sitemap any which way you like - I can easily see how you can adapt this to your specific needs as required. (Although I think I would rather push the route generation down into the template on general principle - that way you won't have to pass the hostname in.)

Comment: Yes... In fact I did, and now I wrote my own controller that does sitemap generation process. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There also is a [PrestaSitemapBundle](https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle) available offering further tools for generating sitemaps in Symfony.